# Window-manager (close,minimize,maximize) buttons does not appear when window is maximized

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d, window-buttons, minimize

My PC is fairly old and the hardware is quite weak, but it runs unity 2D quite well and fast. But I have this only one problem. The close/minimize,maximize buttons dont appear When I open a application window (like writer,calc,etc) and the launcher(sidebar) disappears before the application opens. I notices however when the application opens with the launcher bar on the screen there is no problem. Also when i the buttons dont appear with i click the dash home and return to the window the buttons appear. Is this a bug? is there a fix to this?

Comment: Do the window buttons appear when you hover your mouse over the top-left corner of the screen, where the dash button used to be in 11.04? If yes then it's not a bug. Also, you may consider adding some more details to the question or maybe a screenshot - it's not very easy to follow the question.

Comment: Are you sure they're gone and not just really, really dark? (I ask because I thought they were gone too. I took a screenshot, zoomed in and realised that they were actually just really dark icons.)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Comment: Does this happen with other themes? Radiance, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which theme do you use? Default (Ambience, Radience) or custom?
For old hardware you may try gnome fallback or xfce and cardapio menu as alternative to unity-dash.